# how to make geth notify when any of the accounts receives ether?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a geth running with potentially many accounts. How do I make it execute a command whenever any of my accounts receives a transaction?

in bitcoin, you can use `walletnotify` in `bitcoin.conf`. How to do the same in Ethereum?

Thanks!

Comment: I answered this here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18387/how-to-monitor-all-your-addresses-and-send-payments-out-immediately-to-a-main-ad/18409#18409

Comment: Thank you. I am unable to comment under your answer so I'll just post here. I may need to run a program (option 2) but the loop may be inefficient to handle many many accounts. Is a new block filter better option here? Any code samples?